# Why is my UITableView not displaying what I want it to display?

Tags: uitableview, swift

Numerous tutorials I've been through say the only code I need to display the array I want it to is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var chatListTableView: UITableView!

var friends = ["Anthony", "Antonio", "Andy"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return friends.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "ChatListCell")
    cell.textLabel.text = self.friends[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}  
}
```

However, when I run the app, the `tableView` is still blank. What am I doing wrong? I feel that I am missing something.
All I want to do is display the array in the `tableView`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the ViewController is the datasource and delegate of the tableview

Comment: Thank you very much. All I had was "class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {...}" but I never actually connected the tableview itself to the view controller. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Aci says in his answer, you have to set the data source and delegate of the table view to your view controller. The easiest way to do that is in Interface Builder.